# Local connectedness of topologist's comb

Tags: general-topology, locally-connected

I'm using Croom's textbook, and came with the following definition of local connectedness:

> A space $X$ is locally connected at a point $p$ in $X$ if every open set containing $p$ contains a connected open set which contains $p$.

And the author gives the topologist's comb (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space) $C$ as an example of a connected but not locally connected space. The reason is that each open ball centered at $p:=(0,t)$ with $0<t\le 1$ contains infinitely many open intervals.

I'm not really sure if this is the case, because the set $B(p,r)\cap C$ contains the interval $(\{0\}\times(t-r,t+r))\cap C$ which is open in $C$, contains $p$ and is connected in $C$. Hence $C$ might be locally connected at $p$. So why is $C$ not locally connected?

Comment: $\{0\}\times(t-r,t+r)\cap C$ is **not** open in $C$: there is no open set in $\Bbb R^2$ whose intersection with $C$ is $\{0\}\times(t-r,t+r)\cap C$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oh, of course.. How did I forgot that? Thanks for the comment. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: You’re welcome; done!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

But $\{0\}\times(t-r,t+r)\cap C$ is **not** open in $C$: there is no open set in $\Bbb R^2$ whose intersection with $C$ is $\{0\}\times(t-r,t+r)\cap C$.